# theme cant read my css file path in drupal 7 why?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

why i see this error in console ?

```
 "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/drupal/tooltip/css/layout.css"
```

my files path like this

```
           /* mytheme.info */
            stylesheets[all][]   = tooltip/css/layout.css
            stylesheets[all][]   = tooltip/css/typo.css
```

This files are in my Theme folder

```
Folder: MYTHEME
   File: mytheme.info
   Folder: tooltip
       Folder: css
           File: layout.css
           File: typo.css
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL is wrong: localhost/drupal/tooltip/css/layout.css should be localhost/drupal/sites/all/themes/YOUR_THEME_FOLDER/tooltip/css/layout.css.